# Проектирование базы данных "Задачи на день"

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, проектирование

Появилась задача создать приложение по составлению списка задач на день\неделю\месяц.

Должна быть возможность добавления ежедневных и еженедельных задач.

Подскажите пожалуйста как эффективнее спроектировать реляционную БД в такой ситуации? 
Какие сущности следует выделить?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделим в отдельные сущности Статусы задач, Виды расписания, Задачи, Исполнители, Журнал задач. (Заполнение условное, сделано для наглядности)

```
Статусы задач               Виды расписания
| ID | Имя           |      | ID | Имя    |
|----|---------------|      |----|--------|
| 1  | На выполнении |      | 1  | день   |
| 2  | Выполнена     |      | 2  | неделя |
| 3  | Не выполнена  |
| 4  | Создана       |
| 5  | Передана      |  
|    | другому       |
|    | исполнителю   | 

Исполнители
| ID | Имя          |
|----|--------------|
| 1  | Исполнитель1 |
| 2  | Исполнитель2 |
| 3  | Исполнитель1 |
```

Задачи будем хранить тоже как отдельную сущность, чтобы можно было отделить саму задачу от ее состояния.

```
Задачи
| ID | Описание  | Вид расписания | Дата создания       | Исполнитель  |
|----|-----------|----------------|---------------------|--------------|
| 1  | Описание1 | 1              | 01.01.2015 00:00:00 |      1       |
| 2  | Описание2 | 1              | 01.01.2015 00:00:00 |      2       |
| 3  | Описание3 | 2              | 01.01.2015 00:00:00 |      3       |
```

Изменения состояний задачи будем хранить в отдельной таблице, для того чтобы можно было отследить хронологию изменения состояний и дополнительные атрибуты.

```
Журнал задач
| ID | Задача | Дата                | Статус |Исполнитель |
|----|--------|---------------------|--------|------------|
| 1  | 1      | 01.01.2015 00:00:00 | 4      |            |
| 2  | 1      | 01.01.2015 01:00:00 | 1      |            |
| 3  | 1      | 01.01.2015 02:00:00 | 5      |      2     |
| 4  | 1      | 01.01.2015 02:00:00 | 2      |            |
```

Answer (score 1):

Например одна таблица для сущности "задача", со столбцами start_at, finish_at типа datetime. И еще одна таблица, связанная с "задача", описывающая "повтор" с полями типа daily, weekly, monthly.